# Relation between seminorm of Sobolev space and $L^2$ norm

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let  we have the seminorm of second derivative of  $u$  in $H^2(\Omega)$ i.e.

$|u|_{H^2(\Omega)}=\int_{\Omega} \sum_{|\alpha|=2} D^{\alpha}u $.

Can we derive that $|u|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leq C||\Delta u||_{L^2(\Omega)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

Consider $\Omega$ being a unit circle on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then:

$$
  \int\limits_{\Omega} \sum_{|\alpha|=2} | D^{\alpha}u | =
  \int\limits_{x^2 + y^2 < 1} \left(
    \left| \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \right| + 
    \left| \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} \right| + 
    \left| \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \right|
  \right) dx \, dy
$$

Obviously, mixed derivative is included here, but it is not included in the Laplace operator.

For example, take $u(x, y) = xy$. Clearly, $\Delta u \equiv 0$, but your seminorm has nonzero value, because $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} \equiv 1$.

Comment: One should also mention that such an estimate is possible, if one can control the boundary values of $u$ and $\Omega$ is sufficiently regular. In particular, for $\Omega$ being the (open) unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, one has $\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \le C \, \|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ for all $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ with $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$.